# How do I use different Vim environments?

Tags: vimrc

I want to have something like a `virtualenv` for Vim: on my Windows machine, the plugins are normally located in `vimfiles`, `_vimrc` holds the settings.

For debugging reasons, I want to create a separate environment  with an empty `vimfiles2` directory and a blank `_vimrc2` file.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found it myself: the [`runtimepath`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'rtp') is the solution!

1. create a new `vimrc`, e.g. `new-vimrc`
2. inside that `new-vimrc` set up the `runtimepath` so that it points to a new directory. Sample for Windows:

   ```
   set runtimepath=~/new-vimfiles,$VIM/vimfiles,$VIMRUNTIME,$VIM/vimfiles/after,$HOME/vimfiles/after
   ```
3. Start your Vim now with the `-u` option specifying the location of the new `vimrc` to use:

   ```
   vim -u $HOME/new-vimrc
   ```

Answer (score 1):

An easier way to do this than overriding the `'runtimepath'` setting in your vimrc is to set the `HOME` environment variable for the vim command in your shell command. e.g.

In bash:

```
mkdir ~/new-vimhome
HOME=~/new-vimhome vim
```

Or in the Windows Command prompt:

```
mkdir %USERDRIVE%%USERPATH%\new-vimhome
set HOME=%USERDRIVE%%USERPATH%\new-vimhome
vim
```

(Note that Windows Vim uses the `HOME` environment variable if it is set, but it usually isn't — and other programs won't generally check it — so it should be safe to set it persistently as we do above.)

You can then set up any Vim configuration you desire within that home directory, in the usual way. e.g.:

Bash:

```
mkdir ~/new-vimhome/.vim
touch ~/new-vimhome/.vimrc
```

Windows Command Prompt:

```
mkdir %USERDRIVE%%USERPATH%\new-vimhome\vimfiles
vim %USERDRIVE%%USERPATH%\new-vimhome\_vimrc
```

N.B. As [@eckes notes in a comment](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/14860/how-do-i-use-different-vim-environments/14865#comment25465_14865), this solution does have the caveat that `$HOME` will point to the new directory rather than your *real* home directory, so the `$HOME` environment variable and `~` shortcut can't be used for accessing files located there within an instance Vim running in this way. (Although you can of course still access such files using absolute paths or Windows's standard environment variables.) If you don't want this degree of separation from your usual environment, [their solution](https://vi.stackexchange.com/posts/14861/revisions) might therefore be preferable.

Comment: Well but this would produce a new HOME dir where only Vim lives. Access from Vim to other files in my real HOME would be cumbersome then, won't it?

Comment: @eckes I guess so! I'll add that as a note.